# Как работать с документацией pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Нашёл официальную документацию Pyqt5, но не совсем понимаю как с ней работать, допустим хочу прочитать про класс [QLabel](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtwidgets/qlabel.html) в модуле [QtWidgets](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtwidgets/qtwidgets-module.html?highlight=qtwidgets#QtWidgets), на странице с QLabel прописаны методы, Descriptor: TODO, откуда наследуется (Qframe), но нету точного описания за что отвечает каждый метод и т.п, возможно кто знает как можно улучшить понимание этой документации, заранее спасибо =)

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QLabel.html используйте эту документацию там всё прописано. Нужно нажать на функцию

Comment: Очень сильно вас благодарю =)

Comment: PeFoo, почему вы закрыли вопрос  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1531785/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-layout-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-sizepolicy

Comment: @S.Nick, Нашёл решение на основной вопрос, посчитал что задаю глупые вопросы, дело было в том что картинка была изначально 48x48 из за этого не ужималась меньше этого размера =), могу задать вопрос только по поводу второго, не нашёл ещё решение. Извиняюсь за то что так долго отвечал, не часто захожу на stackoverflow